# Applying function to groupby objects in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
id   salary    days_employed   category    salary_percentile
1    200000         400            1              14
```

where category 0 represents that the person is an early quitter and 1 says that he has stayed longer.

My code is as follows:

```
df1['salary_percentile'] = pd.qcut(df1['salary'], 50, labels=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31','32','33','34','35','36','37','38','39','40','41','42','43','44','45','46','47','48','49','50'])
```

After cutting intp 50 buckets and checking for rows falling in the 37th salary_percentile, this is how my dataframe looks like:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

```
def f(x):
    early_quitter = x.loc[(x.category== '0')]
    non = x.loc[(x.category == '1')]
    proportion_early_quitters = early_quitter.shape[0]/x.shape[0]
    return pd.Series({'prop_early_quitters': proportion_early_quitters})

bypercentile = df1.groupby('salary_percentile').apply(f)
bypercentile = bypercentile.reset_index(level='None')
bypercentile
```

I want my function to return a dataframe that contains the proportion of early_quitters in every group. i.e. in every group, I want to calculate (len(early_quitter)/len(group)). 
When I use this function, it returns a dataframe with 0 proportion for every group.

Can someone help me with this?

On a side note, I created the salary_percentile column using the code shown above.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using Python 2?  If so, try putting `from __future__ import division` at the beginning of your code.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked for me!! I am using Python 2 indeed!! Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, the reason you are getting zeros is because `len` returns an integer and when you do integer divided by integer in python 2, you get an integer whose value is the result of the division with the decimal component truncated.  So "some positive number less than n" / n is equal to zero.  You could fix this with `float(len(early_quitter)) / len(group)`

However, if early quitters are flagged with a 0, and 1 otherwise, the proportion of early quitters is

```
float(len(early_quitters)) / len(group)
```

Or

```
1 - float(len(not_early_quitters)) / len(group)
```

Or because these values are one, `len` produces the same value as `sum`

```
1 - sum(not_early_quitters) / len(group)
```

However, that is the definition of the mean of `not_early_quitters` within the `group`... So

```
1 - mean(early_quitters)
```

You should be able to get this from the variables you've defined with

```
1 - df1.groupby('salary_percentile').category.mean()
```

Comment: I don't think that is what I am looking for. I have edited my question a bit. Can you help me with the edited version please?

Comment: What column are you wanting to calculate the proportion of zeros for?

Comment: Do you have sample data I can work with?  You provided a single row and told us you are cutting it into 50 buckets.

Comment: @Gingerbread I've updated my post.  Hopefully this makes sense.